# What is @permalink and get_absolute_url in Django?

Tags: django

What is `@permalink` and `get_absolute_url` in Django? When and **why** to use it?

Please a very simple example (a real practical example). Thanks

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`@permalink` is a python [decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators), while `get_absolute_url` is a method on a django model.

Both are concerned with allowing you to reverse the URL for a particular object and should be used together. They are used anytime you need to provide a link to a particular object or want to display that object's specific URL (if it has one) to the user

You could simply write your `get_absolute_url` method to return a hard coded string, but this wouldn't adhere to Django's philosophy of DRY (don't repeat yourself). Instead, there is the `@permalink` to make things more flexible.

If you read [the docs on the subject](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#get-absolute-url) you will see how they relate to each other. the `@permalink` decorator hooks into django's URLconf's backend, allowing you to write much more portable code by using [named url patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns). This is preferable to just using `get_absolute_url` on it's own: your code becomes much DRYer as you don't have to specify paths.

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    name = modelsCharField()
    slug = models.SlugField(...)

    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ("blog-detail", [self.slug,])
```

and in urls.py

```
    ...
    url(r'/blog/(?P<slug>[-w]+)/$', blog.views.blog_detail, name="blog-detail")
```

Comment: so, from which package should I import the permalink decorator?

Comment: @permalink is deprecated from 1.11 on. Relevant doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/1.11/#features-deprecated-in-1-11

Answer (score 94):

As of 2013, the Django documentation discouraged use of the permalink decorator and encouraged use of reverse() in the body of the get_absolute_url method.  By 2015, the permalink decorator seemed to have *vanished* without a trace from the Django documentation, and it was finally [removed in Django version 2.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/2.1/#features-removed-in-2-1) in 2018.

So, for a standard DRY way to create a permanent link to a single object view, use `get_absolute_url()` in your model like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
#  NOTE: pre Django 1.10+ this is "from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse"


class MyModel(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('mymodel_detail', args=(self.slug,))
```

and then have an entry in urls.py that points to your view:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w\d\_]+)/$',
    MyModelDetailView.as_view(),
    name='mymodel_detail'),
```

Another nice feature that you get from using `get_absolute_url` is when using the admin app to view the object-editing page, a “View on site” button links directly to this URL.

Comment: In Django 2.0, `reverse` should be imported from `django.urls`, or you'll get a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Answer (score 5):

> in Django 2.1
>   The django.db.models.permalink() decorator is removed.

[source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/2.1/)

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to declare a name for your app in urls.py and then refer to that instead of hard coding anything:

in urls.py:

```py
app_name = 'my_app'

urlpatterns = [
    path('blogs/<int:slug>', blog.views.blog_detail, name='mymodel_detail'),
    ]
```

and in models.py:

```py
from django.urls import reverse


class BlogPost(models.Model):
    name = modelsCharField()
    slug = models.SlugField(...)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('my_app:mymodel_detail, args=[self.slug,])
```