# When to use Django get_absolute_url() method?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Django documentation says:

> `get_absolute_url()` method to tell Django how to calculate the canonical URL for an object.

What is canonical URL mean in this is context?

I know from an SEO perspective that canonical URL means picking the best URL from the similar looking URLs (`example.com` , `example.com/index.html`). But this meaning doesn't fit in this context.

I know this method provides some additional functionality in Django admin, redirection etc. And I am fully aware of how to use this method.

But what is the philosophy behind it? I have never actually used it in my projects. Does it serve any special purpose?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

First of all, when it comes to web development you really want to avoid hard coding paths in your templates. The reason for this is that paths might change, and it will be a hassle to go through all your HTML and templates to find every single URL or path and update it manually. It makes your code much harder to maintain.

The solution to this is to define functions that return the URL instead. This is where `get_absolute_url()` comes into the picture.

Example:

```
<!-- Bad -->
<a href="/language/category/product/{{product.pk}}">Link</a>

<!-- Good -->
<a href="{{product.get_absolute_url}}">Link</a>
```

### Canonical URL

Your second question is what a canonical URL is. A canonical URL is "the official" url to a certain page. Sometimes an asset can be displayed in multiple different URL's, for example:

```
/en/shoes/1-nike-shoes/
/en/shoes/1-nike-shoes?sort=price&order=asc
/en/shoes/1-nike-shoes?sort=price&order=desc
```

Here we have the same asset displayed in 3 different URL's. The "Canonical URL" would be the one we defined as the main one. E.g. `/en/shoes/1-nike-shoes/`.

Its very useful to define what a official or "main" URL to a certain asset is. It will allow you to prevent duplicate content when search engines index your website.

In the context of the quote you are using from the Django Documentation. "Canonical" in this case means "the official URL where this model is displayed".

Answer (score 23):

See this example:

I want to generate a unique URL for each product, the pattern will be - http://...../products/abcdefg/ (after '/products/'    it's my slug value). 
In models.py, I created the 'get_absolute_url' that will generate url in the above pattern

**models.py**

```
class Products(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f"/products/{self.slug}/"
```

**productlist.html** - get_absolute_url referred in anchor tag

```
{% for obj in object_list  %}
   <a href="{{obj.get_absolute_url}} ">{{obj.title}}</a> <br>
{% endfor %}
```

**urls.py** - my url pattern

```
 path('/products/<slug>/', ProductDetails.as_view()),
```

Comment: Or better yet, use the view name using reverse:

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("viewname in urls.py", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

Answer (score 12):

You create models for your website. When a new instance is made for a model, django must know where to go when a new post is created or a new instance is created.

Here `get_absolute_url` comes in picture. It tells the django where to go when new post is created.

Answer (score 6):

`get_absolute_url` allows to keep your object DRY. To have a url which defines that object instance. In most case a detail page for that object.

Couple this with `models.permalink` and you can define the object detail url very easily.

[What is @permalink and get_absolute_url in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503645/what-is-permalink-and-get-absolute-url-in-django)

Later if you change the structure of the url you have to modify only in one place, the urls.

Comment: I know from seo perspective that canonical url means picking the best url from the similar looking urls (example.com , example.com/index.html). But this meaning doesn't fits in this context.

Comment: I was suprised because it's the first time I read something about the @permalink decorator. Actually, it's not documented anymore and is probably deprecated now. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16322584/1887976