# how to write url in a-Tag Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

```
<a href="{% url 'news-year-archive'  %}">2012 Archive</a>
```

Or

```
<a href="/news-year-archive">2012 Archive</a>
```

Both method is work but which method is best for production

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43179875/when-to-use-django-get-absolute-url-method/43180219 there is an answer here you can read it. it will help you with the best approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because both method work fine on local and server the method that is shorter is better ;