# Django url link error Reverse for 'category' with keyword arguments '{'category.id': 1}' not found. 1 pattern

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to create a product filter, filtering  it by category, so I decided to send the category id trough an URL and then filter all products by the specified ID, but im getting troubles to implement it.

```
Reverse for 'category' with keyword arguments '{'category.id': 1}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['category/<int:category\\.id\\Z']
```

views.py:

```
def category(request, category_id):
    products = Product.objects.filter(category=category_id)
    return

 render(request, 'product/category.html', {'products': products})
```

models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=False, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("product:category", kwargs={"category.id": self.id})
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('detail/<int:product_id', views.detail, name="detail"),

    path('category/<int:category.id', views.category, name="category")
]
```

HTML Template, I tried two ways,none of them worked:

```
{% for category in categories %}
{{category.id}}
<a href="{{category.get_absolute_url}}"></a>
{% comment %}
<a href="{% url 'product:category' category_id=category.id %}"></a>
{% endcomment %}
{% endfor %}
```

models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=False, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=False)
```

Comment: It should be `category_id` not `category.id` in urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `category_id` not `category.id` in urls.

Also need `>` at the end with closing `/`, so try below urls:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('detail/<int:product_id>/', views.detail, name="detail"),

    path('category/<int:category_id>/', views.category, name="category")
]
```

Comment: just something im in doubt the get_absolute urls how does it work? like it got the patternd category_id witrhout me doing something like category_id={{category.id}}

Comment: @KaynanKaynanFelipeRodrigues What mean?

Comment: @KaynanKaynanFelipeRodrigues But I'd recommend you to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43179875) question for further clarification.